# Reload tensorflow model in Golang app server

Tags: go, tensorflow

I have a Golang app server wherein I keep reloading a saved tensorflow model every 15 minutes. Every api call that uses the tensorflow model, takes a read mutex lock and whenever I reload the model, I take a write lock. Functionality wise, this works fine but during the model load, my API response time increases as the request threads keep waiting for the write lock to be released. Could you please suggest a better approach to keep the loaded model up to date?

**Edit, Code updated**

Model Load Code:

```
    tags := []string{"serve"}

    // load from updated saved model
    var m *tensorflow.SavedModel
    var err error
    m, err = tensorflow.LoadSavedModel("/path/to/model", tags, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Exception caught while reloading saved model %v", err)
        destroyTFModel(m)
    }

    if err == nil {
        ModelLoadMutex.Lock()
        defer ModelLoadMutex.Unlock()

        // destroy existing model
        destroyTFModel(TensorModel)
        TensorModel = m
    }
```

Model Use Code(Part of the API request):

```
    config.ModelLoadMutex.RLock()
    defer config.ModelLoadMutex.RUnlock()

    scoreTensorList, err = TensorModel.Session.Run(map[tensorflow.Output]*tensorflow.Tensor{
        UserOp.Output(0): uT,
        DataOp.Output(0): nT},
        []tensorflow.Output{config.SumOp.Output(0)},
        nil,
    )
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding **code**

Comment: Why you have to reload the model every 15 minuts? Can't you just let it loaded in memory and use it when it's needed?

Comment: The model is being continuously trained. And we need to be able to use the latest model as and when its available. Thats why this hack. This is our first attempt at trying tensorflow in the production environment so we might be making rookie mistakes. Since the time I asked the question, we have also explored tensorflow-serve which seems best suited for the task at hand.

Comment: I guess the way to go is to train the model and export it every time the training finish, using a different tag. Then from Go check if the currently loaded model has a different tag and in that case, load it in memory. I guess. What's your actual solution instead?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, we have moved to tensorflow-serve. It manages the lifecycle of the model, loading the new model once it is available on the local file system and unloading the old model once the new one is available. The only problem that we were facing was with the loading/unloading of the model. Hence this has been working perfectly fine with us and also using less memory/storage.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably destroyTFModel takes a long time. You could try this:

```
old := TensorModel

ModelLoadMutex.Lock()
TensorModel = new
ModelLoadMutex.Unlock()

go destroyTFModel(old)
```

So destroy after assign and/or try destroying on another goroutine if it needs to clean up resources and somehow takes a long time blocking this response. I'd look into what you're doing in destroyTFModel and why it is slow though, does it make network requests to the db or involve the file system? Are you sure there isn't another lock external to your app you're not aware of (for example if it had to open a file and locked it for reads while destroying this model?).

Instead of using if err == nil { around it, consider returning on error.